# Can't Remove PPA By add-apt-repository?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa

I noticed that in `sudo apt update` I have an error:

```
Ign:3 https://dl.bintray.com/etcher/debian stable InRelease              
Err:16 https://dl.bintray.com/etcher/debian stable Release                    
  403  Forbidden [IP: 52.35.230.20 443]
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                     
E: The repository 'https://deb.etcher.io stable Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I tried removing it using the typical method of `add-apt-repository --remove ppa:X/Here`, but this didn't work:

```
sarah@LesserArk:/etc/apt$ sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:https://dl.bintray.com/etcher/debian
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~https/ubuntu/ppa'.
ERROR: '~https' user or team does not exist.
sarah@LesserArk:/etc/apt$ sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:"https://dl.bintray.com/etcher/debian"
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~https/ubuntu/ppa'.
ERROR: '~https' user or team does not exist.
sarah@LesserArk:/etc/apt$ sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:dl.bintray.com/etcher/debian
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~dl.bintray.com/etcher/debian'.
ERROR: '~dl.bintray.com' user or team does not exist.
sarah@LesserArk:/etc/apt$ sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:bintray.com/etcher/debian
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~bintray.com/etcher/debian'.
ERROR: '~bintray.com' user or team does not exist.
sarah@LesserArk:/etc/apt$ sudo add-apt-repository --remove etcher/debian
```

Nothing I seem to do works, what should I do to remove the PPA?

Comment: Did you add that repository using that method? It's not a PPA.

Answer (score 5):

If you added it with.

```
echo "deb https://deb.etcher.io stable etcher" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/balena-etcher.list
```

Then to remove it you need to append `deb` also.

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove "deb https://deb.etcher.io stable etcher"
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/balena-etcher.list
sudo apt update
```