# Getting a failed to fetch when running apt-get update with bintray

Tags: apt, updates

Running `sudo apt-get update` on ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS is giving me this error:

```
Hit:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease
Ign:2 http://binaries.erlang-solutions.com/debian focal InRelease
Hit:3 http://binaries.erlang-solutions.com/debian focal Release
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/21.04/prod hirsute InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Err:9 https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 35.155.141.94 443]
Hit:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 35.155.141.94 443]
E: The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How can I run an update without getting this error?  Is it a matter of somehow removing this repository to get updates from?

The last thing I did was try and install the `dotnet` sdk on my system:

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb
```

But I haven't run an update in a while so maybe it could have been something else...

**Update**

I am unable to update my server now b/c of this error.  Is there a way to just skip this repository somehow?   Does this package get read by everyone or is it just mine instance b/c I was trying to install a package and now it has added this repo to my list of resources to check for updates?

**Update 2**

ls -alFh /etc/apt/sources.list.d

```
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4.0K Nov 22 16:08 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  183 Dec  3 12:25 erlang-solutions.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  183 Dec  3 12:25 erlang-solutions.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   91 Dec  3 12:25 microsoft-prod.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   91 Dec  3 12:25 microsoft-prod.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   40 Dec  3 12:25 sbt.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   40 Dec  3 12:25 sbt.list.save
```

cat /etc/apt/sources.list

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable
```

Comment: did you see this https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/6445

Comment: Are you having a lot of ppas?

Comment: @someone what do you mean?  sorry not sure I understand.

Comment: did you see this https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/6446, the repository is not publicly accessible. try to add new repo`https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/debian` from their community.

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri  How do I remove and add that one?

Comment: remove the responsible ppa as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1214685/cant-remove-ppa-by-add-apt-repository)

Comment: @lemrm  I'm confused b/c I don't recall adding it explicitly.... so I'm not sure of the command to remove it

Comment: Please see fully updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

I will first answer your specific questions, ...

1. *How can I run an update without getting this error?*
   *Is it a matter of somehow removing this repository to get updates from?*
   *Is there a way to just skip this repository somehow?*
   (I am listing them all together since they have all the same answer).
   Yes, see comand `sudo mv ...` suggested below.
2. *Does this package get read by everyone or is it just mine instance b/c I was trying to install a package and now it has added this repo to my list of resources to check for updates?* It gets read by everyone, since the changes were introduced in a system-wide location, `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

... and then expand as follows.

---

You have to clarify what you want to do.
For the various cases:

1. If you simply want to update, remove the failing repos from your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.
   You could apply [several methods](https://itsfoss.com/how-to-remove-or-delete-ppas-quick-tip/) to remove ppas added to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, e.g. simply renaming files `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/<myppa>.list` to something like `<myppa>.list.save`.

   ```
    $ sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list.save
   ```

   This way, you would keep your files just in case.
   That should be enough to get you going.
2. If you additionally want to update `sbt`, execute

   ```
    $ echo "deb https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/debian all main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
    $ echo "deb https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/debian /" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt_old.list
    $ curl -sL "https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x2EE0EA64E40A89B84B2DF73499E82A75642AC823" | sudo apt-key add
    $ sudo apt update
    $ sudo apt install sbt
   ```

   Commands slightly modified from [this official source](https://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html)  (`apt-get` -> `apt`).
   Old repos https://dl.bintray.com/loadimpact/debian and https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/sbt-1.5.5.deb are now `forbidden`.
   This is similar to what *abu-ahmed al-khatiri* quotes.
3. If you want to update other packages that belong to failing repos, then please clarify that, so we can help with the specific cases.

---

I also note a couple of points about your Microsoft products.

1. You installed `packages-microsoft-prod.deb` from 16.04. You should install the package [for the correct version, 20.04](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#2004-).
2. [It is often safer](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/gdebi.1.html) to use `sudo gdebi <pkg>.deb` than `sudo dpkg -i <pkg>.deb` (as instructed in item 1 above).
   In this case, given that instructions come directly from MS, it is likely the same.
3. You are hitting a repo for *hirsute 21.04*, `Hit:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/21.04/prod hirsute InRelease` (likely in your `microsoft-prod.list`).
   You should remove that and add the repo for *focal 20.04*. Follow [these instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/linux-package-repository-for-microsoft-software#ubuntu) under *Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal)*.

---

I suggest you post in the question the output of

```
$ uname -a
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
$ ls -alFh /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

**Related**:

1. [Can no longer use sudo apt update. Running 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345665/can-no-longer-use-sudo-apt-update-running-20-04)

Comment: ok I see sbt.list and sbt.list.save in the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ folder.... should I remove those 2 entries?

Comment: updated my quesiton with those directory values...

Comment: @Blankman - `*.save` are not read by `apt`, so you would be ok with only removing `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list`.
You still have to clarify if you only mean to get rid of the errors, or if you need sbt from somehere in the galaxy.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Err:9 https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  InRelease     
>  403  Forbidden [IP: 35.155.141.94 443]     
>  ...   
> E: Failed to fetch https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 35.155.141.94 443]   
> E: The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  InRelease' is no longer signed.    
> N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
> ```

That's mean the repo is not publicly accessible [2].

**What should you do:**

1. Remove the old Repo

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository --remove "deb http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /"   
   sudo rm -fv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
   sudo rm -fv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list.save
   sudo apt update
   ```

   Based on your sources list. simply remove `.list` files.
2. Install sbt package from new Repo [3]

   ```
   sudo apt install apt-transport-https curl gnupg -yqq
   echo "deb https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/debian all main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
   echo "deb https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/debian /" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt_old.list
   curl -sL "https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x2EE0EA64E40A89B84B2DF73499E82A75642AC823" | sudo -H gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring gnupg-ring:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/scalasbt-release.gpg --import
   sudo chmod 644 /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/scalasbt-release.gpg
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install sbt
   ```

   or you can install sbt package from TGZ archives through sdk manager:

   ```
   wget https://github.com/sbt/sbt/releases/download/v1.5.5/sbt-1.5.5.tgz     
   sudo tar xzvf sbt-1.5.5.tgz -C /usr/share/     
   sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/sbt sbt
   sdk install sbt
   ```

---

**Additionally**
The ssl of https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x2EE0EA64E40A89B84B2DF73499E82A75642AC823 may not work on 18.04 since it's using a gnupg. we can download the public key using web API. Run:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com:443 --recv 2EE0EA64E40A89B84B2DF73499E82A75642AC823
```

---

Hope this Helps.

**Related:**

- [1] https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/6445
- [2] https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/6446
- [3] https://github.com/apache/tvm/pull/7926

Comment: strange, I ran your first 3 commands to remove and running `sudo apt update` it gave the same error again...

Comment: @Blankman see my updated.

Comment: it works!  for my error here:

Get:25 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages [1444 kB]
Err:26 https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 35.155.141.94 443]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted amd64 Packages [13.5 kB]

E: Failed to fetch https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 35.155.141.94 443]
E: The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  InRelease' is not signed.

[Container] 2021/12/03 21:52:43 Command did not exit successfully apt update exit status 100

Comment: @AliSarshogh see my updated.

Answer (score 1):

Bintray is shutdown and not hosting sbt repository anymore so You need to update sbt repo.

First remove source list files of old sbt repo.

```
sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt*
```

Also check `/etc/apt/source.list` file and make sure that you remove entries of old sbt repository.

Install new sbt repository source list and gpg key.

```
echo "deb https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/debian all main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
echo "deb https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/debian /" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt_old.list
curl -sL "https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x2EE0EA64E40A89B84B2DF73499E82A75642AC823" | sudo apt-key add
sudo apt-get update
```